# Copy Excel Chart into Word Document Resizing

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, paste

I'm attempting to make an excel sheet that has a button "Generate Report" where as I click it, it opens up a document and writes a report based on the excel sheet. I have everything going good for me except pasting charts in to the word document. Every time I paste it into word using VBA the sizing is all off, like this: [image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

My code is:

```
'Charts
Worksheets("Input").ChartObjects("Chart_Antenna").Chart.ChartArea.Copy

With wordapp
.activedocument.bookmarks("Chart").Select
.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
DataType:=PasteJPEGFilePicture, _
Placement:=Tight
DisplayAsIcon = False
End With
```

Comment: try replacing `DataType:=PasteJPEGFilePicture` with `DataType:=PasteMetafilePicture`

Comment: I did! it does the same exact thing

Comment: Is there a way to set the width and height of the chart through VBA?

Comment: Following up on Asgar's comment, below that answer: Do you get the same behavior if you copy/paste manually?

Comment: @CindyMeister nope! it pastes to fit perfect

Comment: Where did you get this: `Placement:=Tight`?  This is not a valid specification for the Placement argument of PasteSpecial. Is the object coming in in-line with the text or "floating"? And is it the same type when you paste manually (in-line or floating)?

Comment: It's in-line when I paste manually, but even if I use Placement:=InLine nothing changes

Comment: It needs to be `Placement:=wdInLine` - you have to use values VBA understands. Read the information in the help...

Comment: FWIW I get the impression the bookmark is in a table or something. But, yes, it's possible to resize an InlineShape. An InlineShape has Width and Height properties.

Comment: @cindy what would the code look like if I were to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you assigned to `PasteJPEGFilePicture`and `Tight`. If you paste as Bitmap inline, then it's sized according to the page width.

If you will use a reference to `Microsoft Word x.x. Object Library` for early binding, you may use `Word.Range` and the ENUM values `wd...`.

```
Dim r As Object              ' Word.Range
With wordapp
    Set r = .ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Chart").Range
    r.Collapse 1             ' 1 = wdCollapseStart, 0 = wdCollapseEnd
    r.PasteSpecial _
        Link:=False, _
        DataType:=4, _
        Placement:=0, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False ' 1st 4 = wdPasteBitmap, 2nd 0 = wdInLine
End With
```

Comment: It's still sizing the same exact way

Comment: just the first line of the second page

Comment: word.range isn't a user defined type?

Comment: Glad to be a lifesaver ... and then please mark my answer as answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).